# Android app failing to load feeds on LG phones only

Tags: android, json, networking, connection

So currently the app tries to load feeds as json objects and parse them to fill the listview. If its unable to make the REST connection or null objects are returned it throws an alert to user that connection not working properly. But currently on LG phones it is reported that their connection were fine, but still the app was unable to load feeds and kept throwing alert  when user selected the option to retry.

It works fine on other phones, probably, and the bug been reported are for LG spectrum, cayman, revolution.

I am not sure whether adding other test case for active connection would help, but it would still not solve the problem above when connection present and it either returns null or unable to connect. I am unable to reproduce the problem on the devices iam testing on.